# Is there a word that means "a force that formed the universe from an original chaos?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "a force that formed the universe from an original chaos?".  I found this description surrounding the word "nous" in the past, but it doesn't look like it held on the wiki.

Comment: Unfortunately, EL&U only answers questions that are in the English language, so "any language" might cause this question to be closed. I think it's an intriguing question and would not want that to happen, perhaps change the "any language" to something more appopriate. Wonderful question, though!

Comment: P.S. do you want a more biblical (Genesis 1) poetic word for this or a more modern scientific "big-bang theory" word?

Comment: To my mind, all language groups have a word for a higher being! To dig deeper is to find a word like 'logos'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about English, but about all languages.

Comment: Its a question about force that presupposes a force, One such force is identified by the 'big bang' theory,  another is the type exemplified by ideas such as the 'hand of God'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because first - it asked about other languages than English, and second - after the edit, answers, question and comments no longer match.

Comment: Can someone with access reopen this question?

Comment: The question is indeed within the topic of this site, but the answer to it is that there is **no word** with precisely this meaning that would be **theory neutral**. If one embraces a particular philosophical/religious/scientific theory about how the universe came into being, then one can say what the name for such a 'force' is within that theory. But there is no generally accepted word for it that one could use without committing oneself to a particular theory about it. The answers given so far confirm that, because each of them is dependent on certain theoretical assumptions.

Comment: Does "the wiki" mean Wikipedia?

Comment: "first cause" is the usual phrase in english / philosophy for this type of thing.

Comment: creatio ex nihilo....

Comment: I do not know if this is the correct meaning of the word, but I immediately thought about disentropy.

Comment: The law of conservation of energy states that energy can neither be created nor destroyed - only converted from one form of energy to another.

Comment: In the last five years, there’s been a renewed interest in bounce cosmology, which recasts the Big Bang as a Big Bounce (Force) from a previous era. The new symmetry-based approach might be useful for distinguishing between the higher-point correlations of a universe that inflated and one that bounced. “The mechanism would be different; the symmetries are different,” Pimentel said. “They would have a different menu of cosmological correlations.” https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-origin-of-time-bootstrapped-from-fundamental-symmetries-20191029/

Comment: No, because jsw29 is correct.

Beyond that, is it not clear a force which formed the universe, particularly "… from original chaos…” doesn't come into the realm of physics?

If you seriously want this to belong to SE EL&U then the obvious Answer would be "God…" with no reference at all to which God, or when or how.

My suggestion would be to take the same Question to a site dealing with philosophy or religion… or keep looking at dictionaries, on paper or on line.

Comment: Buddhists do not believe in a creation story. They believe that the world has simply existed forever and continues to recreate itself in the continued repetition of life and death.

Comment: The “chaos” part is highly problematic, as that isn’t necessarily a part of either a physics or religious view of the state just before everything got started.

Answer (score 19):

primordial as defined by Merriam-Webster, "existing in or persisting from the beginning (as of a solar system or universe)"

I believe you are describing a primordial force of sorts

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Primordial comes from the latin Primordius, literally meaning "first to begin"

Comment: *Primordial* simply describes something that was present or existent at the beginning of something; it doesn't necessarily form the universe from chaos, which is a highly specific task.

Comment: @Conrado: I agree that primordial isn't a good fit for this since it just situates something in time. The chaos that precedes creation is just as primordial (possibly more so) as the entity/force that transforms it. What the OP is looking for is the thing that causes the event which separates the universe into the primordial and the postordial(?)

Comment: that's why I said a primordial *force*

Comment: @小奥利奥: I don't want to be pedantic - primordial force does capture a lot of the flavor of what the OP was asking about but 1) it's a phrase and not a word, and 2) it still just specifies *when* the force was at work and not that it has anything to do with creation. For example, in Greek mythology Cronus is the primordial god of time but does not create anything.

Comment: if something predates a primordial force then it isn't primordial.

Comment: @小奥利奥: Primordial doesn't mean "That very first thing that existed", it means "That which existed at the beginning". The beginning being the first *period* of time not the very first *moment* in time. There can be many primordial things and some of them can predate other ones. For example, in greek mythology there is a set of gods referred to as "primordial" many of which are descendants of each other (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_primordial_deities) and in astrophysics there are primordial black holes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) which come *after* the big bang

Comment: as the user above stated, it is derived from that Latin term "primordius" which literally means "first to begin"

Comment: @小奥利奥: *Autochthonous* is derived from the Greek term "autochthon" which literally means "people who sprang from the earth". If you say something is autochthonous in English you don't mean it literally sprang from the earth. Same thing with *primordial*. Regardless of its latin roots, in modern English it does not mean "strictly the first thing ever" as evidenced by the examples I gave above.

Answer (score 18):

**Demiurge**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demiurge

The demiurge is the entity or force responsible for creating the universe and might be a bit more specific than **creator** which has more mundane usages (e.g. "She's the creator of that website"). It is also more specific than references to God or some other supreme being, since the demiurge is only responsible for the act of creation and is not necessarily God.

Comment: Demiurge has negative connotations as a result of its associations with a specific religion (Gnosticism), though.

Comment: In many religions, the Demiurge is not the Creator, but shaped a universe that had already been created.

Comment: @nick012000: I associate it with Platonism more than Gnosticism, but you're right there's definitely a strong association there. Does Gnosticism still have negative connotations though? (Honestly curious, I figured at this point, most of these early Christian sects were viewed through a neutral historical lens rather than as still controversial)

Comment: @Mattia: it's not that gnosticism is looked upon negatively, but that gnosticism looks upon the demiurge negatively.

Answer (score 14):

I can't speak about other languages, but *prime mover* is a good answer in English. https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=prime+mover

Comment: You might also consider the similar "First cause".

Answer (score 10):

**Creator**

For example from [Platonic Idealism](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Overland_Monthly/HfwMAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=creator%20formed%20universe%20from%20chaos&pg=PA391&printsec=frontcover) in *Overland Monthly*, October 1890, at page 391:

> The Creator formed the universe out of chaos

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is "Creator" as in the proper noun. My friend's high-school dropout cousin calls himself a "creator," but his cringey videos are nowhere near a force capable of forming the universe.

Comment: @scohe001 Note that, as a proper noun or Divine epithet, it’s capitalized, and as a common noun, it isn’t. This usually removes any ambiguity.

Comment: Reverential capitals are not a writing convention, they're a way of showing religious or political reverence (as well as being old-fashioned). They don't work for this type of disambiguation, both because they've gone out of style and because the writer may not have religious reverence for some abstract philosophical concept.

Answer (score 5):

If one has a particular philosophical or religious or scientific theory about how the universe came into being, and that theory postulates some sort of a 'force' that brought it into existence, then that theory is likely to give a name to it. One will then be able to say that, **according to that theory**, that's what the 'force' is. Several such terms have been pointed to in the already posted answers to this question. Each of these terms is, however, dependent on a particular theory, and makes sense **only within the context of that theory**.

The answer to the question, in so far as it is a question about English language, and not about philosophy or religion or science, is that there is **no word with this meaning that would be theory neutral**. There is no generally accepted word for such a 'force' that one could use without committing oneself to a particular theory about it.

It should be noted that the 'force' in question, if it exists, must be something vastly different from the forces that operate within the universe, hence the quotation marks around the word, in this answer. Moreover, the idea of a 'force' that creates the universe out of 'an original chaos' is conceptually problematic, because it postulates the 'force' and the 'chaos' as somehow preceding the universe, even though the universe is supposed to comprise everything that exists.

Comment: But a model (or theory) is already implied, isn't it? "A force that formed the universe from an original chaos" takes for granted (1) primordial chaos, (2) an agent of change, and (3) an event of formation. The event is sometimes called a Singularity

Comment: @Conrado, a type of a theory is indeed implied by the question, but there are different specific theories within that type.

Answer (score 1):

**catalyst** could have this meaning:

> 2. Someone or something that encourages progress or change
> 3. An inciting incident that sets the successive conflict into motion.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catalyst) (1st definition is mainly about chemistry)

If you're looking for something to use in a literary sense, this has the benefit of implying your meaning while not being tied down to any specific religious doctrine.  If you're looking to describe an event that created the entire universe, you might capitalize it as "the Catalyst".

Answer (score 1):

The word “Logos” as in John 1:1 - In the beginning was the Word (Logos), and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

Comment: Can Word be a synonym of Sound, i.e. a spoken sound. Thus, in the beginning was the 'Sound' A Primordial Sound?

Comment: If one links John 1:1 to the original words of Genesis 1:3   1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters. 3 And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.”
then, I suppose, one could “ listen” to both the “spirit” - which in Hebrew is something akin to a bird flapping its wings over the waters linked to the chaos/dragon Tiamat- and at the actual Word(s) God utters to bring on creation.

Comment: ...God utters... is the part I am looking into. utter (adj.) "speak, say," c. 1400, in part from Middle Dutch uteren or Middle Low German utern "to turn out, show, speak," from uter "outer," comparative adjective from ut "out" (see utter (adj.)); in part from Middle English verb outen "to disclose," from Old English utan "to put out," from ut (see out (v.)).

Comment: By looking at my ‘The Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology, I see that Logos many mean “argument, discourse, saying (rarely), word, rel. to ‘logein’...recount, say...(p. 535). Therefore you may not have to go to any other word than “Logos” to get to a “Primordial Sound.”  This is specially so if you link John to Genesis.

Comment: Please clarify - to ‘logein’...recount, say...(p. 535) - I couldn't fully understant it.

Comment: Sorry, in TODoEE the term is ‘legein.” Please look it up ’ online or Liddell and Scott, etc.  It is probably Greek and related to “law/lex” “order/logos” and other such logos-like words and definitions..

Comment: Tried to look-up previously, Will try again. Thanks

Comment: As you wish. Thanks

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, your search reminds me of Tolkien’s ideas of sound/music -  in The Silmarillion,-  being primal at the beginning of the universe. I wouldn’t doubt it if he was using a much older tradition there.

Comment: Thanks for sources. Moderator has deemed this to be extended chat. I like the Legein angle as precursor to logo, however, so far it has thwarted my logos/sound-energy (force) discussion as I need to, now, investigate the 'gathering of words' (Legein) implications. Reminds me of someone akin to Champollion, picking out Hieraglyphs and trying to understand them!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120439/discussion-between-ferjsoto42yahoocom-and-huggy).

Comment: I don’t think this answer is useful in this context. A native English speaker would probably take *Logos* to mean word or thought (or the plural of “logo”), whereas Creator would be understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's — *a,* not necessarily capitalized — **god**.

Obviously, this word is not really specific to English; it is probably, next to "human", "danger" and "food", among the first handful of words in *any* language.

The reason for this answer is that you asked for "a force that formed the universe from original chaos". This implies **intent:** "Forming" is different from spontaneously emerging (even if I have personally never seen order spontaneously emerging anywhere — quite to the contrary!); and it implies **transcendence,** because the force you describe is *extraneous* to the universe.

The word for a transcendent entity acting with intent is *god.* There is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

**higher being** (plural higher beings) A non-human life form believed to have power over human life, such as the Christian God.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Define+higher+being

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is a little too specific; the only word that I can think of that comes close and is universal enough is the Greek ἀρχή (*arche*). It implies both origin and "order" (rule). The word νοῦς (*nous*) has traditionally been considered one such *arche*.

Comment: This answer misleadingly ignores the vast differences among the Greek philosophers who used the word, or whose views were paraphrased by using that word. It has often been used in the ways that do not at all fit the OP's idea of a 'force' operating on some pre-exisiting chaos. It is also less than clear what exactly is the 'tradition' that is alluded to in the last sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chaos was the force that formed the universe from an original VOID.

The Universe began from a void, not from 'chaos'. Chaos would be a something. The start of the Universe is supposed to be from a nothing!

The Greek God, Chaos is mythologically responsible for the creation of 'something' from the void.

The idea that the beginning was 'creating order from chaos' is spurious. Life IS chaos, that's what it is. I don't mean in the sense of chaos being a disaster, not at all! I mean, life is limitless, unorganised, spills forth naturally, is untamed, free, giving, infinite. Like, buds shooting, rivers flowing, trees branching...

Consciousness has always existed, because it is infinite. Consciousness created reality by 'conceiving of something' - having an idea. This manifested 'reality' - an ongoing physical expression of infinite consciousness. Maybe 'thought' is another answer?

https://www.greekmythology.com/Other_Gods/Chaos/chaos.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not what this site expects, but the "force" to create some ordering (like day vs. night, land vs. sea, etc.) out of chaos is called "energy" as the unordered state (chaos) has less energy than any other state.
Also If you believe in the big bang theory, the original state wasn't chaos, but all mass and energy concentrated in one point...